# Yii2 How can I display Activeform radioList data on screen?

Tags: yii, yii2, html-encode, active-form

I have not experience with Yii2. 
I would like to be able to show the result of a form on the screen.
With the fields name and email I have no problem but I can not show the selection
that I make of my radioList. 
I have tried many methods but none works.
Can you help me please?

These are my files.

SiteController.php

```
  public function actionEntry()
    {
        $this->layout = 'print';
        $model = new EntryForm();

        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->validate()) {
          return $this->render('entry-confirm', ['model' => $model]);
        } else {
          return $this->render('entry', ['model' => $model]);
        }
    }
```

EntryForm.php

```
namespace app\models;

use Yii;

class EntryForm extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
    public $name;
    public $email;
    public $category;

      public function rules()
        {
        return [
            [['name', 'email'], 'required'],
            ['email', 'email'],


        ];
    }
```

entry.php

```
use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;

<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>
    <?= $form->field($model, 'name') ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'email') ?>
    <?= $form->field($model, 'category')->radioList([
        1 => 'radio 1', 
        2 => 'radio 2'
    ]);
     ?>


   <div class="form-group">
        <?= Html::submitButton('Submit', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) ?> 

    </div>


<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

entry-confirm.php

```
<p>You have entered the following information:</p>
<ul>
    <li><label>Name</label>: <?= Html::encode($model->name) ?></li>
    <li><label>Email</label>: <?= Html::encode($model->email) ?></li>
    <li><label>Category</label>: <?=  Html::encode($model->category) ?></li>

</ul>
```

[This is the image with the problem:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FkeZo.jpg)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand... Do you want to encode radioList options' labels? If so: `<?= $form->field($model, 'category')->radioList([1 => Html::encode('radio 1'), 2 => Html::encode('radio 2')]);` should be enough.

Comment: Bizley thank you very much for your answer.
I have added an image to my post. I think the problem is clearer with the image.

Comment: @Bizley I have add my files to the post. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

1. In model extending ActiveRecord you must never explicitly define properties that are the same as names of columns in DB.
2. You must define at least one validation rule for each attribute that is set by the end user, otherwise system will not allow to set it.